# Using IN Clause to Select By Attributes in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, where-clause

I am working in ArcMap 10.1, trying to write a script to automate the selection of a feature class. I have two input parameters:

```
stop1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
stop2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

I want to use those input paramenters with an IN statement. So if stop1 and stop2 are found in the "Address" field, the expression would look something like this:

```
expression = ''' "Address" IN '{0}','{1}' '''.format(stop1,stop2)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer,"NEW_SELECTION",expression)
```

I've manipulated the **expression** equation several ways, but it errors out every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

```
expression = "Address IN ('{0}','{1}')".format(stop1,stop2)
```

Using round brackets to encompass your value list is documented at [SQL reference for query expressions used in ArcGIS](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm):

> Selects a record if it has one of several strings or values in a
>   field. When preceded by NOT, it selects a record if it doesn't have
>   one of several strings or values in a field. For example, this
>   expression searches for four different state names:
>
> ```
> "STATE_NAME" IN ('Alabama', 'Alaska', 'California', 'Florida')
> ```